# SharePoint Online Search control not in Suite bar

Tags: online

The search control bar in our SharePoint Online sites is not on the O365 Suite bar. It is still on the right side of the site's navigation header along with the "Share site" link. Is there anything I need to do on my tenant to get this update? [image: Seat]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set [Targeted release](https://docs.microsoft.com//office365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH&view=o365-worldwide) for select users or your entire tenant. This change is still in process of rolling out.